# Build Dynamic Layout For restaurant

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am developing canvas using jquery and i am able to take only one kind of image from toolbox to actual canvas(i.e. drag, drop of one image from toolbox to canvas). I want to add more inputs in toolbox like door,table,chair etc. And want to use same for drag drop operation.

This is my Current Code which takes only one input in toolbar. i want multiple options in toolbar and same for drag drop functionality in the canvas.

```
// get a reference to the house icon in the toolbar
// hide the icon until its image has loaded
var $house=$("#house");
$house.hide();

// get the offset position of the kinetic container
var $stageContainer=$("#container");
var stageOffset=$stageContainer.offset();
var offsetX=stageOffset.left;
var offsetY=stageOffset.top;

// create the Kinetic.Stage and layer
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 350,
  height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// start loading the image used in the draggable toolbar element
// this image will be used in a new Kinetic.Image
var image1=new Image();
image1.onload=function(){
  $house.show();
}
image1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/4top.png";

// make the toolbar image draggable
$house.draggable({
  helper:'clone',
});

// set the data payload
$house.data("url","house.png"); // key-value pair
$house.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
$house.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
$house.data("image",image1); // key-value pair

// make the Kinetic Container a dropzone
$stageContainer.droppable({
  drop:dragDrop,
});

// handle a drop into the Kinetic container
function dragDrop(e,ui){

  // get the drop point
  var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
  var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);

  // get the drop payload (here the payload is the image)
  var element=ui.draggable;
  var data=element.data("url");
  var theImage=element.data("image");

  // create a new Kinetic.Image at the drop point
  // be sure to adjust for any border width (here border==1)
  var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    name:data,
    x:x,
    y:y,
    image:theImage,
    draggable: true
  });
  layer.add(image);
  layer.draw();
}
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
#toolbar{
  width:350px;
  height:35px;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h4>Drag from toolbar onto canvas. Then drag around canvas.</h4>
<div id="toolbar">
  <img id="house" width=32 height=32 src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/4top.png"><br>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```